# How to specify custom mime type in cfhttp?

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am working with an API and the XML mime type needs to be application/atom+xml. The XML type that ColdFusion uses is not the one I need and the API I am working with is giving back an error because of it. Is there anyone to set a custom mime type? I do not want to have to go the route of making a temporary file every time and setting the type on there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<cfhttp url="...">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/atom+xml" />
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: +1 after rereading the question - not clear to me if this is about serving or consuming.

Comment: he is consuming a web service.  the web service requires a specific mime type for the request.  The Google Calendar API has this same requirement for some of the API methods.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're trying to serve the XML from ColdFusion use the [cfcontent tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c82.html) as such:

```
<!--- what ever algorithm you need to generate the XML to serve --->
<cfcontent reset="true" type="application/atom+xml">
<cfoutput>#xmlValue#</cfoutput>
```

The "reset" attribute tells ColdFusion to cancel out anything buffered for output previously.